# How to resize page (page layout) and all content/images at same time

Tags: adobe-indesign

Looking to resize pages, and all content in pages to remain in same proportion. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Do you have Photoshop available?

Comment: Does the content need to be editable afterwards? If not, you may quickly sidestep the issue by exporting your page as a `pdf` or hi-res `jpg` and placing that in the smaller page layout.

Answer (score 1):

Indesign has Alternate Layout options, such as Liquid Layout. These are used for designing content for different digital and print mediums.

Adobe has an overview of this workflow here.
https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/alternate-layouts-liquid-layouts.html

Read up on these alternate/liquid layouts, as they're probably your best bet.